# Grunt module does not execute

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I spent a few hours last night trying to get my grunt module to execute but can't. Grunt acts like it executed the function but it actually doesn't.

Here is the grunt module: https://github.com/chrisabrams/grunt-commonjs-aws-s3

If you say `grunt s3-generate` it comes back and says "Done, without errors." - but if you `console.log` something inside the function, it never fires. I just need to know why it never fires.

Here is an example project that shows the grunt module doesn't run: https://github.com/chrisabrams/stackoverflow-grunt-example

Comment: Can you post your `Gruntfile` or like, any code at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `s3-generate` task is a multitask configured to read `this.options()` which means your config should look like:

```
's3-generate': {
  options: {
    dest: 's3.js',
    key: 'a',
  },
  target: {}
}
```

If your task isn't going to handle files directly consider using `this.data` in your task to access the raw object literal passed to `s3-generate`.